# Submit form by clicking on drop down menu item

Tags: php, html

I have a drop down menu like this. How can I submit a form value just by clicking it into the menu (using PHP)?
Thanks!

```
<form action="partita_squadre.php" method="post"> 
<fieldset>
<legend>Insert match</legend>
    <select name="giorn" >

        <?php

        echo "\t<option value=\"\">--MATCH--</option>\n";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 38; $i++) {
            echo "\t<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }

        ?>

    </select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a [client-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) method ([Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript)) in order to achieve what you wish to do.

[PHP](http://www.php.net/) doesn't fire up on its own with an `onchange` method, since it's a [server-side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting).

Use JS => `onchange='this.form.submit()'` for the select.

(Tested and working using FF 28.0 and IE 7)

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['giorn'])){
    $i = $_POST['giorn'];
    echo $i;
}

?>

<form action="" method="post"> 
<fieldset>
<legend>Insert match</legend>
    <select name="giorn" onchange='this.form.submit()'>

        <?php

        echo "\t<option value=\"\">--MATCH--</option>\n";

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 38; $i++) {
            echo "\t<option value=\"$i\">$i</option>\n";
        }

        ?>

    </select>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No way using only PHP? Thanks anyway!

Comment: No, you need JS to do what you're asking, and you're welcome. @SirAnderson PHP is a server-side language and not client-side and does not fire up on its own like that.